# ClickOnce taking long to download and install

Tags: clickonce

Has anyone else experience this...on machines which I have an application updated via ClickOnce, it takes almost 10-20 mins to download and install a 2MB install...this was working fine until I reached my 26th build...and after that.I checked the network and it's normal...I ran the installer on a new machine and it was lightening fast! so I am thinking it might have to do with the prior installations on the machines.

Is ClickOnce maintaining a cache on the client machines, perhaps that needs cleaning?

Comment: did you resolve the problem or just determine it wasn't related to cached clickonce files?  if you did resolve it, what was the issue?

Comment: The problem was on the hosting enviornment, RackSpace Cloud. After they moved my VM to a different host all seems notmal now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce keeps the current version and one previous.  That shouldn't be the issue.

The first place I would check is the server where the files are deployed.  Run [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) while your app updates to see what exactly is going on with the network traffic.

In addition, you may want to look into [compressing your ClickOnce traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515254).  It can make a huge difference in your download sizes.