# Embed files into ClickOnce setup.exe

Tags: clickonce

I have ClickOnce installer. Some people have slow internet connection, so I'd like to embed all files into setup.exe. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to embed files into one setup.exe file with ClickOnce.  ClickOnce requires access to the manifest and the extracted files to know which files to update.  ClickOnce only updates the files that have changed with each release.  You can however use HTTP Compression on IIS to greatly reduce the total size of the download for your users with slow connections.

Here is a related SO question that provides information on how to enable IIS Compression with ClickOnce.

[IIS Compression with ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515254/can-clickonce-deployed-application-setup-be-compressed)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommemd this course of action. If you embed the files in the exe, it will take as much time to download them every time you publish an update. If they are separate, and the files are not changed between deployments, they will be copied from a locally-cached version instead of copied across the network again.